# JFrame SetEtxtendedState Restore Down doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I want JFrame Restore Down but after maximizing it , but it doesn't restore down. I don't want Jframe hide the windows taskbar as well.  Do I miss step here ?  What I did until now is below .

My JFrame is undecorated

I calculated **Screen Rectangle Size** here ;

```
    private Rectangle screenRect = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

Setting Screen **JFrame Maximum Size** here ;

```
       this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(screenRect.width , screenRect.height));
```

**MAximize Button Action**

```
         private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

           this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
           this.setSize(screenRect.width , screenRect.height);
       }
```

**Restore Down** Button Action **which is not working**

```
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      this.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);

   }
```

### MCVE

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   private Point initialClick;
   private Dimension rv;
   private Point p;
   final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   final Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
   final int taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;
   private Rectangle screenRect = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();

           this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(screenRect.width , screenRect.height));

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setUndecorated(true);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseDragged(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Minimise");
        jButton1.setFocusable(false);
        jButton1.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Maximized");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("x");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Restore Down");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(609, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(52, 52, 52))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(333, 333, 333))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jPanel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
               int thisX = this.getLocation().x;
        int thisY = this.getLocation().y;

        // Determine how much the mouse moved since the initial click
        int xMoved = (thisX + evt.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
        int yMoved = (thisY + evt.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);

        // Move window to this position
        int X = thisX + xMoved;
        int Y = thisY + yMoved;
        this.setLocation(X, Y);
    }                                    

    private void jPanel1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
         initialClick = evt.getPoint();
    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        this.setState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

          this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
          this.setSize(screenRect.width , screenRect.height);
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

          this.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);


    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        dispose();
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: please I'm don't want to Assume whatever, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, just about empty JFrame caused wiht a.m. issue,

Comment: hey you can see entire code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/c7uhv9t6sqzy2bu/Jframe%20Doesn%27t%20Restore%20Down.txt?dl=0

Comment: *"..entire code here dropbox.."*  People want to see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ***here*** at SO.

Comment: It seems to restore from maximized just fine here, BTW.

Comment: it doesn't work after maximizing , I dont know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to calculate the current location of JFrame so before its maximized , I solved the my self thanks for  help !

```
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       thisXcurrent = this.getLocation().x;
       thisYcurrent = this.getLocation().y;                   
       rv = this.getSize();
       this.setSize(screenRect.width, screenRect.height);
       this.setLocation(0, 0);


}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      this.setSize(rv);
      this.setLocation( thisXcurrent,  thisYcurrent);


}
```